# Checking / rescuing sql query in rails 5.2 raises and error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The DeployedSkill object references a ValuesList object which provides a limited value domain to users answers. An additional "filter" field contains an expression to filter even more the values of the domain. Values are instances of the Value class, belonging to the ValuesList object.

The model looks like this:

```
class DeployedSkill < Skill
  ### before filter
  before_validation :set_code

  # Custom validation of the filter attribute
  validate :values_filter
  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :business_object_id, case_sensitive: false}, length: { maximum: 32 }

  belongs_to :template_skill, :class_name => "DefinedSkill", :foreign_key => "template_skill_id" # helps retrieving the skill template
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "DeployedObject", :foreign_key => "business_object_id"

  belongs_to :values_list, inverse_of: :deployed_skills


  ### private functions definitions
  private

  ### format code
  def set_code
    if self.code[0, 3] == "DV_"
      self.code = self.code[3 .. -1]
    end
    self.code = "#{code.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '_')}".upcase[0,32]
  end

  def values_filter
    begin
      puts "----- Test the filter -----"
      Value.where("#{filter}").first
    rescue
      puts "----- Filter test failed -----"
      self.errors.add(:filter, "is not correctly specified")
      puts self.errors.map {|error, message| [error, message]}.join(', ')
    end
  end
end
```

Before saving the updated DeployedSkill, I validate that the filter expression is compatible with a database query.
Using ByeBug, I can see that the test works fine, and an error is added to ActiveModel::Errors list when filter's syntax is not correct:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000012bf03a8 @base=#<DeployedSkill id: 638, playground_id: 0,
business_object_id: 632, code: "SAKO1_METHODE", blablabla ... , 
type: "DeployedSkill", filter: "'xxx'", global_identifier: nil, sort_code: "SAKO1_METHODE", 
physical_name: nil>, 
@messages={:filter=>["is not correctly specified"]}, 
@details={:filter=>[{:error=>"is not correctly specified"}]}>
```

The console echoes it:

```
----- Test the filter -----
  Value Load (10.2ms)  SELECT  "values".* FROM "values" WHERE (code like 'S%) ORDER BY "values"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
----- Filter test failed -----
filter, is not correctly specified
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Nevertheless, the update method instruction:

```
      if @deployed_skill.update_attributes(deployed_skill_params)
```

breaks into an error:

```
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction was aborted, commands are ignored until the end of the transaction : 
SELECT exists( 
  SELECT * FROM pg_proc 
  WHERE proname = 'lower' AND proargtypes = ARRAY['character varying(255)'::regtype]::oidvector ) 
  OR exists( SELECT * FROM pg_proc INNER JOIN pg_cast ON ARRAY[casttarget]::oidvector = proargtypes 
  WHERE proname = 'lower' AND castsource = 'character varying(255)'::regtype )
```

At this point, I have no idea of what's going on, and I don't know where to search deeper.

I hope you can help me to understand the issue and find the solution!

Thanks!